# MySQL Conditional Joins

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to conditionally join on multiple columns in mysql.  Basically, I want to look that if it table A doesn't match table B of that column I'd like to try and get it to match on the next one.  My first check would be:

```
Join A.Acct = B.Acct.
```

If it fails to join during that process if table B doesn't have a record to match A then do

```
Left Join A.Phone=B.Phone OR LEFT Join A.Phone=B.Phone2 OR
```

LEFT JOIN 
    A.Phone=B.PHONE3

Comment: Please format your code correctly, see the formatted output below the edit box. Please write 'left join' in just one way. Please read & act on [mcve]. Your join syntax is wrong, you need an ON. Read a definition of left join: it returns what inner join does plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. For inner join determine what condition has to hold for a row to be kept from all possible combinations of a row from each table; put that in your ON. Your case may involve multiple joins and/or OR in ON. But your description of what you want is so unclear that I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple `left join`s and choose the right value in the `select`:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(b.?, b1.?, b2.?, b3.?) as whatever
from a left join
     b
     on a.acct = b.acct left join
     b b1
     on a.phone = b.phone left join
     b b2
     on a.phone = b.phone2 left join
     b b3
     on a.phone = b.phone3;
```

`?` is the column that you want to select from `b`.  You need a separate `coalesce()` expression for each one.

Comment: Yes, ideally if I get a match on the account number I wouldn't need to join on the others.  But if that fails then would like to join on the phone columns in table B to see if any of them will produce a match.  Thanks!